# ModuleNotFound error in django in Django tastypie web application

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am pretty new to Django.

When i try to include the urls from the api.py file it returns me an error.

Here is api.py file from the articles app folder

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.constants import ALL
from article.models import Article


class ArticleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        querySet = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
```

here is the urls.py file from the article app folder

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from article.views import *
from .api import ArticleResource
from django.conf.urls import include

article_resource = ArticleResource()

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^api/',include('article_resource.urls'))
]
```

and the error i get back is this

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0470C9C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\Desktop\programs\mydjango\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 29, in <module>
    url(r'^articles/',include('article.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\Desktop\programs\mydjango\mysite\article\urls.py", line 16, in <module>
    url(r'^api/',include('article_resource.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Vineeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'article_resource'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing quotes from include will solve the problem

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^api/',include(article_resource.urls))
]
```

**NOTE**: Django `include` functions uses python's `import_module` to import the module from string, but here, the `article_resource` is only available in your local scope.